# How can I set my WatchFaceService as the default launch activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, wear-os

I have a WatchFaceService (WatchFace) and every time I run my application it switches to the SimpleFace and then I have to set mine as the watchFace which ends up to be quite frustrating after many restarts.

To notice this does happen with the new Android Studio 2

I read around S.O. how to set the default activity but that does not do the same job as my WatchFaceService is not an activity but a service.

Also via the UI of Android Studio 2 it cannot be selected.

Is there a way to achieve this ? I think it might be difficult because actually it's not running an app, but setting the watch's Watchface at every run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that this isn't possible. Your watch face is a `Service`, after all, so there's no way that it can be the default (launch) `Activity` for your app. They're completely different component classes.

But you **can** get close.

What you need to do is create a tiny little shell `Activity` that contains only the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER)
            .putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                    new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                            MyWatchFaceService.class.getName()));
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}
```

...where `MyWatchFaceService` is the class name of your watch face service (surprise). You'll also need to declare it in your manifest, of course:

```
    <activity android:name=".FaceActivity"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true">
    </activity>
```

Finally, configure your Wear module in Android Studio to launch `FaceActivity` when you run the app. This is under the Run menu, in Edit Configurations.

Having done that, run your app from AS onto the watch, and it'll open the watch face chooser on-device, with your face selected. From there, one tap will start it.

I can't see a way to eliminate that single tap, though.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow and report back. Good night.

Comment: Worked like a charm. ! I hope in future releases this can be done more easily